# What to do with "no .travis.yml found"?

Tags: github, cmd, travis-rb

I'm trying to set up Travis and work on xv6 (because of a university assigment), but I'm got a few errors and that "no .travis.yml found" was one that stopped me completely (I wasn't even sure of what I was doing before that, just following instructions).

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: So... did you try adding that file? Give a [mcve], this is unanswerable as posted.

Comment: Thought it was a more straight foward problem, but now I think that I was wrong.

After configuring Git, with git remote add original and all of that, I triggered the build without problems (i"t passed") and created a branch called "project_1" "travis setup releases --force". Didn't work, so I renamed the repository in github, followed all the steps again and, instead of "project_1", I treid with "project_2" and "project_3" hoping it would fix it, but there is where I get the error.
Idk if that's enough information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the thing was pretty simple. My pc was showing me the files without the extension, so it showed me it was called ".travis.yml", when in fact it was called ".travis.yml.txt" (I noticed when I used dir in the cmd).

I know it was pretty silly, but I'm not hiding the fact that I'm still a noob. Hope it helps someone